# Jquery remove item from localstorage if the link is already clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

I have a page with a few filters for search results. These filters are links and upon clicking, I am adding the id to localstorage. When the page reloads it looks in the localstorage if the id of the link exists, it modifies the css of that particular link. I am able to achieve this.
Now, when the same link is clicked again, I need to be able to remove the id of the link from localstoarage so it does not change the css when the page reloads.

**Before Clicking** 
[image: Before Clicking]

**After clicking**
[image: After Clicking]

Here is my code. Some kind people from StackOverflow helped me get this piece of code together. I need it to extend. Please let me know if any of this doesn't make sense. Would gladly rewrite my sentences.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  //localStorage.clear();
  var cached = localStorage.getItem('filters');
  var filters = (cached) ? JSON.parse(cached) : {};
  for (id in filters) {
    $('#' + id).addClass('li-checked');
  }
  $('.li-filter').click(function(e) {
    //event.preventDefault();
    $(e.target).addClass('li-checked');
    $(e.target).removeClass('li-unchecked');
    var id = $(e.target).attr('id').toString();

    if (filters[id]) {
        filters[id] += 1;
      //filters = $.grep(filters, function(e) { return e.id!=id });

    } else {
        filters[id] = 1;

    }
    console.log(JSON.stringify(filters));
    localStorage.setItem('filters', JSON.stringify(filters));
  });
});
```

Comment: First: use toggleClass instead of addClass and removeClass. second: what does filters[id] += 1 mean?

Answer (score 0):

@Rohit If I understood your question correctly, onclick you have to add a class and remove it in case it is already clicked.
For this scenario, I will suggest writing functionality to toggle classes that can help.
You need to get class on the element while li is clicked.

```
if($(e.target).attr("class").contains("li-checked"))
{
    $(e.target).removeClass('li-checked');
    $(e.target).addClass('li-unchecked');
}
else if((e.target).attr("class").contains("li-unchecked"))
{
    $(e.target).removeClass('li-unchecked');
    $(e.target).addClass('li-checked');
}
```

If the class is 'li-checked' then remove it and add 'li-unchecked'
and if the class is 'li-unchecked' then remove it and add 'li-checked'

I hope it helps.

Comment: Hi Hemant, thanks for the prompt response. This isn't working. It does not retain the clicked value like it was earlier.

Comment: @Rohit My understanding is, values are stored in local storage but there is problem while clicking li item again, so code is replacement of first 2 lines in click function.
Kindly revert in case there is something I misunderstood and can help further.

Comment: I tried replacing the code Hemant, but it did not. Instead it stopped working altogether. It was no longer storing the value in localstorage.

Comment: @rohit please help with html as well, I will try to run it locally. Thanks

Comment: @RohitPrasad I think code is not working since, first time when li item is clicked there is no class. Hence either a else block can be used to add li-checked class first time.
While a better alternative is to use toggleClass - https://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/
Since using toggle class will prevent the use of if-else block of code.